# jQuery - fadeIn and out bug with logo

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm having a problem with the animation continually queuing and flipping out. I have spent far too long on this and i am in need of some serious help lol. Your help would be much appreciated :)

So what i am trying to achieve is after the 'user' has scrolled past the header/banner, the navigation and logo re-size and fix itself to the top of the viewing window. So as they scroll it stays at the top, so they can use the navigation anywhere on the page, and when they return back to the top it all changes back to the previous header/banner.

Now my problem here is that when it changes the logo's and fades them, they queue up and keep fading in and out if you scrolled to the top up and down a few times and just looks really really buggy... I'm not sure how to fix this. (btw some of the code below is working fine, and it's not all relevant, the problem lies within #banner & #banner_mini)

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var yOffset = $("#header").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 200) {
            $("#header").css({
                'top': 0,
                'background-color' : '#000',
                'position': 'fixed',
                'filter': 'alpha(opacity=90)',
                'height': '50px',
                '-moz-opacity': '0.9',
                '-khtml-opacity': '0.9',
                'opacity': '0.9'
            });
            $("#banner").fadeOut(100).delay(400);
            $("#banner_mini").fadeIn(300);
            $("#menu").css({'margin-top':'0px'});
            $("#menu ul li a").css({'font-size':'12px', 'padding':'5px', 'margin-top':'0px'});

        } else {
            $("#header").css({
                'background-color' : '',
                'top': yOffset + 'px',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'height': '200px',
                'filter': 'alpha(opacity=100)',
                '-moz-opacity': '1',
                '-khtml-opacity': '1',
                'opacity': '1'
            });
            $("#banner_mini").fadeOut(100).delay(400);
            $("#banner").fadeIn(300);
            $("#menu ul li a").css({'font-size':'14px', 'padding':'10px', 'margin-top':''});
            $("#menu").css({'margin-top':'147px'});
            }
    });
});

</script>
```

these are the two div's it's changing:

```
<div id="banner">
        <img src="img/Logo_PNG_edit.png"  width="193" height="187" />
        </div>
        <div id="banner_mini" style="display:none">
        <img src="img/Logo_mini.png" width="162" height="29">
        </div>
```

I would really appreciate any help to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [jQuery .stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).  It will stop all currently running animations.  Do this before you start your next animation.

Here's an example of usage when applied to your code.

```
$("#banner").stop(true, true).fadeOut(100).delay(400);
$("#banner_mini").stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);
```

The first parameter will clear your queue when passed true.  The second parameter will move the current animation to it's end state.

Answer (score 1):

`if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 200)`
// This condition results `true` once you pass 200 `scrollTOP` i.e. it will be called at 201, 210, 500, 600 and so on and so does the `else` part.

So, just check, if they have already achieved the `position` you wanted.

```
var yOffset = $("#header").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 200) {
        if ($("#header").css('position') !== 'fixed') {
            $("#header").css({
                'top': 0,
                'background-color': '#000',
                'position': 'fixed',
                'filter': 'alpha(opacity=90)',
                'height': '50px',
                '-moz-opacity': '0.9',
                '-khtml-opacity': '0.9',
                'opacity': '0.9'
            });
            $("#banner").fadeOut(100).delay(400);
            $("#banner_mini").fadeIn(300);
            $("#menu").css({
                'margin-top': '0px'
            });
            $("#menu ul li a").css({
                'font-size': '12px',
                'padding': '5px',
                'margin-top': '0px'
            });
        }
    } else {
        if ($("#header").css('position') !== 'absolute') {
            $("#header").css({
                'background-color': '',
                'top': yOffset + 'px',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'height': '200px',
                'filter': 'alpha(opacity=100)',
                '-moz-opacity': '1',
                '-khtml-opacity': '1',
                'opacity': '1'
            });
            $("#banner_mini").fadeOut(100).delay(400);
            $("#banner").fadeIn(300);
            $("#menu ul li a").css({
                'font-size': '14px',
                'padding': '10px',
                'margin-top': ''
            });
            $("#menu").css({
                'margin-top': '147px'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yup yup. Didn't think of that when I was putting my answer in.  I would recommend sticking in a data attribute and checking that though so you don't use styling to determine logic.

Comment: You're welcome. Always mark 'answer' to the reply which helped you.